# Copy value from table to another if not like 0

Tags: mysql, sql

what Im trying to do is copy value between 2 tables only if value webId from table domains is different than 0. This is giving me error:

```
BEGIN

SET new.referralWebId=domains.webId if webId from domains where webId not like '0';

END IF;

END
```

This is for a BEFORE INSERT statement in customers table.
Does anyone have a solution?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add more details as to what the error you get is.

Comment: you have an error in your mysql syntax near 'if webId from domains where webId not like '0';

END IF;

END'

Comment: What is data type of `domains.webId` ? And how do you want to handle if more than one row contains `webId` without `'0'` ??

Comment: Hi Ravinder, only if webId equals 0 then function should trigger.. at least that is my intention.

Comment: What's in each table?  How do you want to match up the rows to update, with the rows in `domains`?

Comment: for each new row in customers table, I need to set referralWebId same value that colum webId in domains table, only if that column value in domains is different than 0.